# GWT Fragment Idenfiers

Tags: gwt

So far what I have used with my gwt application is a simple FI, like `#login`, `#welcome` etc.
However I want to "refactor" my application in a more descriptive way, I need make it this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/main#login
http://localhost:8080/main#search
http://localhost:8080/profile#<username>
http://localhost:8080/api
etc.
```

Can I do this with GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay on the same GWT application, you'll have to use the HTML5 History API (`pushState` and `onpopstate`) instead of GWT's default `History` (or `DefaultHistorian`) implementation; which means your app would only work with browser supporting the HTML5 History API (or you'd have to provide a fallback).
This is possible with GWT, but if you don't know how to do it and/or how the HTML5 History API works, it'll cost you a lot (of time).

BTW, if you ever switch to the HTML5 History API, why keep some fragment identifiers?

The alternative is, as *milan* says, to split your app into smaller parts (`/main`, `/profile`, `/api`, etc.)

Comment: Er, have X modules, with X `EntryPoint`s, instead of a single one?

Comment: I've never tried this, what I have used is GWT-Multipage. How do you implement this? If I make multiple EntryPoint classes how do I know which one is to load?

Comment: Think of them as totally distinct apps (which they are). Compiled separately, producing distinct outputs.

Comment: I wrote a blog post based on Thomas Broyer suggestion and skeleton in:
http://carlosaguayo.posterous.com/html5-history-in-gwt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but /main and /profile are going to be separate (html) pages, so you'll have EntryPoint for each then (loading/unloading GWT modules). Is that want you want? Google's AdWords is an example (written in GWT), each tab is a separate HTML page (/dashboard/, /cm/CampaignMgmt, ...).

Comment: Yes that's what I want, how to do loading/unloading GWT modules BTW?

Comment: actually I used GWT Multipage, and with separate EntryPoints, if I have a User model (like authenticated User object), it will not be available when using separate EntryPoints...

Comment: You'd have to reload your session obviously. Yes, GWT needs a session too.